# Using HTTPX for Tornado testing

Tags: testing, pytest, tornado, python-asyncio, httpx

I'd like to standardize the use of [HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org/) for testing regardless of the Python web framework being used. I managed to get it to work with Quart and FastAPI, but I'm having issues with Tornado since it doesn't comply to ASGI, and it uses a particular asynchronous implementation, although it is currently based on asyncio.

The minimal application to test is divided in three parts: `main.py`, `conftest.py` and `test_hello.py`.

**app/main.py**:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import Iterator

from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler

from loguru import logger


async def start_resources() -> None:
    '''
    Initialize resources such as async Redis and Database connections
    '''
    logger.info('resources started...')


async def close_resources() -> None:
    '''
    Release resources
    '''
    logger.info('resources closed...')


class HelloHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self) -> None:
        self.write({'hello': 'world'})


@contextmanager
def create_app() -> Iterator[Application]:
    IOLoop.current().run_sync(start_resources)
    try:
        app = Application([
            ("/hello", HelloHandler),
        ])
        yield app
    finally:
        IOLoop.current().run_sync(close_resources)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with create_app() as app:
        http_server = HTTPServer(app)
        http_server.listen(8000)
        logger.info('Listening to port 8000 (use CTRL + C to quit)')
        IOLoop.current().start()
```

**tests/conftest.py**:

```
from typing import Iterator, AsyncIterable

from httpx import AsyncClient
from pytest import fixture
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOLoop
from tornado.web import Application

from app.main import create_app  # isort:skip


@fixture
def app(io_loop: AsyncIOLoop) -> Iterator[Application]:
    '''
    Return a Tornado.web.Application object with initialized resources
    '''
    with create_app() as app:
        yield app


@fixture
async def client(app: Application,
                base_url: str) -> AsyncIterable[AsyncClient]:
    async with AsyncClient(base_url=base_url) as _client:
        yield _client
```

**tests/test_hello.py**:

```
from httpx import AsyncClient
from pytest import mark


@mark.gen_test
async def test_hello(client: AsyncClient) -> None:
    resp = await client.get('/hello')
    assert resp.status_code == 200
    assert resp.json() == {'hello': 'world'}
```

And the project structure is this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_hello.py
```

And the error I get

```
$ pytest tests/test_hello.py 
========================================================================== test session starts ==========================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /tmp/minimal-app
plugins: tornado-0.8.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                        

tests/test_hello.py F                                                                                                                                             [100%]

=============================================================================== FAILURES ================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________ test_hello _______________________________________________________________________________

client = <async_generator object client at 0x7f78e3de75f8>

    @mark.gen_test
    async def test_hello(client: AsyncClient) -> None:
>       resp = await client.get('/hello')
E       AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'get'

tests/test_hello.py:7: AttributeError
------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr setup -------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-17 10:21:28.574 | INFO     | app.main:start_resources:15 - resources started...
----------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr teardown ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-17 10:21:28.595 | INFO     | app.main:close_resources:22 - resources closed...
======================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================
FAILED tests/test_hello.py::test_hello - AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'get'
=========================================================================== 1 failed in 0.03s ===========================================================================
```

Comment: Maybe the client that you are passing is an awaitable and not a client instance (yet). You could try await (await client).get(...) or something similar

Comment: for some reason, `mark.gen_test` is causing this issue. If I change it to `mark.asyncio`, this error disappears and a new timeout error pops up.

Comment: I don't remember where, but I found that asyncio and tornado are incompatible and require a particular setup. I think you'll have to set the async loop manually in order to use the same for both pytest-asyncio and httpx

Comment: Since Tornado 5.0, IOLoop uses asyncio behind the scenes. So, it seems weird that it doesn't work with `mark.asyncio`.

Comment: Have you tried with https://github.com/eugeniy/pytest-tornado

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried to use `client = AsyncClient()` instead of `async with` in the `@fixture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work replacing `pytest-tornado` fixtures for a custom one and adding `alt-pytest-asyncio` to support asynchronous tests. `pytest-tornado` is not necessary anymore.

**conftest.py**:

```py
from typing import AsyncIterable, Iterator

from httpx import AsyncClient
from pytest import fixture
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOLoop
from tornado.testing import bind_unused_port
from tornado.web import Application

from app.main import create_app  # isort:skip


@fixture
def io_loop() -> AsyncIOLoop:
    '''
    Copied from https://github.com/eukaryote/pytest-tornasync/blob/master/src/pytest_tornasync/plugin.py#L59-L68
    '''
    loop = IOLoop()
    loop.make_current()
    yield loop
    loop.clear_current()
    loop.close(all_fds=True)


@fixture
def app(io_loop: AsyncIOLoop) -> Iterator[Application]:
    '''
    Return a Tornado.web.Application object with initialized resources
    '''
    with create_app() as app:
        yield app


@fixture
async def client(app: Application) -> AsyncIterable[AsyncClient]:
    '''
    Start a HTTPServer each time
    '''
    http_server = HTTPServer(app)
    port = bind_unused_port()[1]
    http_server.listen(port)
    async with AsyncClient(base_url=f'http://localhost:{port}') as _client:
        yield _client
```

**pyproject.toml**:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
tornado = "^6.0.4"
pytest = "^6.0.1"
httpx = "^0.13.3"
loguru = "^0.5.1"
alt-pytest-asyncio = "^0.5.3"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```